# Cifrar parametros de url con javascript

Tags: javascript, hash, php8, cifrado

Tengo la siguiente funcion definida en una etiqueta  con el atributo onclick, la cual me redirecciona y envia los siguientes parametros.

```
function datos_mach(id) {
  var numero_contenedor = $("#numero_contenedor" + id).val();
  var type_descarga = $("#type_descarga" + id).val();
  var ISO_container = $("#ISO_container" + id).val();

  location.href = "inspeccion_mach.php?id_container=" + id
    + "&numero_contenedor=" + numero_contenedor
    + "&ISO_container=" + ISO_container
    + "&type_descarga=" + type_descarga;
}
```

Lo que necesito es una manera de cifrar los valores de dichos parametros para que en la siguiente pagina no aparezcan en la url y sean modificables.
Investigue algo y vi la funcion EncodeComponent(), pero no la pude implementar correctamente.
Favor podrian ayudarme o al menos decir si es posible cifrar dichos valores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una referencia de la posible solucion es esta, pero quisiera saber como se puede implementar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Encriptarlos solo haría mas tedioso el proceso, pero no impediría que se modificaran y se pudiera mandar cualquier valor encriptado (pues la encriptación ocurre en el cliente, y por definicion todo lo que envia el cliente es "inseguro")... Cual sería el propósito de "no querer" que se vean en la URL o cual es el proposito para que no puedan mandar cualquier otro valor cambiado? (quizas hay una mejor manera de solucionar ese caso de uso.

Comment: tengo la observación porque al modificar los datos, altera el insert y me enviaria un registro alterado a mi DB, como forma de seguridad buscaba que llege encriptado al cliente para que asi no los pueda ver y modificar.

Comment: Pero por lo que deduzco, los valores que se envian en esos parámetros vienen de inputs? como validarías si lo que te está llegando realmente es lo que un usuario escribio o es algo "modificado"? El contexto no es muy claro para poderte proponer alguna alternativa.

Comment: provienen de unos input hidden, los cuales los mando con ajax del lado del servidor. por lo que son  input con datos extraidos de una consulta sql, para luego dichos input con dichos valores los paso a otra ruta con esa funcion javascript que esta en imagen. lo que necesito es que al pasarlos como parametros, los pueda cifrar para evitar que los modifiquen.

Comment: Y no tienes ningun identificador unico para esos datos? Es que sin saber mas del contexto es muy complicado darte alguna alternativa, esos datos son de que? a quien pertenecen? tienes algun ID relacionado a esos datos? habría posibilidad de que envies solo ese id y vuelvas a consultar los datos en el servidor... Se me ocurren varias ideas... pero dependemos totalmente del contexto y de los datos que se estén calculando y enviando... Pero creo que la alternativa definitivamente no es "encriptar" los datos en la URL, pues perfectamente entonces podrían editar el valor del input antes de enviar

Comment: Prueba a hacerlo en el backend, haciendo un post , hasheas lo que quieras en el backend y redirijes a la pagina.